# Unique canvases in Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, meteor

I am trying to loop through a collection and draw a specific image to a canvas for each item in the collection. I am having difficulties getting it to draw the correct image on each canvas, rather it is drawing the same one on all of them.

```
<ul id="settings-photos">
    {{#each photos}}
        {{> photo}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>

<template name="photo">
    <li>
        <canvas data-time="{{timestamp}}"></canvas>
    </li>
</template>
```

I can successfully create canvases with unique timestamps (pulled from the collection item). An item in my Photos collection looks like

```
_id: "PQWhyTQGwyBoZuxRs"
format: "jpg"
timestamp: "1431998534049"
user: "Sw6CdzqQzk49kkQ2M"
```

When the template is rendered, I build an image path using the user and timestamp values, load it into an image, and then draw to my canvas.

```
Template.photo.rendered = function () {
    var canvas = this.find('canvas');
    console.log(canvas); // "<canvas data-time="1431998534049" height="375"></canvas>"
                         // Loads the correct unique data from each collection item

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var user = Meteor.userId(); // "Sw6CdzqQzk49kkQ2M"
    var time = this.data.timestamp; // "1431998534049"
    var path = user + "_" + time + ".jpg";

    console.log(path); // "Sw6CdzqQzk49kkQ2M_1431998534049.jpg"
                       // Again, correct path to the image referenced by the correct item

    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300,375);
    };
    img.src = path;

};
```

All of the values produce the correct information that should lead to the right images being drawn. Unfortunately, the image from the second (of only two, but is the first to render) items is drawn on both canvases, despite the path being correct in the first one. If I manually insert to Photos a new item, the canvas will draw the correct image. However upon refresh it reverts to the incorrect first-loaded image.

My data-time attribute is unnecessary however it allows me to differentiate between the elements for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not 100% certain this is the issue, I suspect this has to do with a missing `var` when assigning to `img`. If this is the case the following should work:

```
var img = new Image();
```

This could lead to the bug, since a missing `var` could make the JavaScript engine interpret `img` as being the same, global variable for each div. Since the code most likely get to run for each div before any of the callbacks activate, only the value that the last div assigned to `img` would be read, when they do run. This would cause all the callbacks to draw the same image to the canvas, namely the last one.

Comment: Hence the need to hoist!